# install vue-loader on an angularjs application

Tags: angular, vue.js

I have a *rails/angular* app, and I thought to migrate to **vue**. For migrating   I need to start load `.vue` files in my application with `vue-loader`

```
import vueComponent from './myVueComponent.vue';
```

I don't want to change the structure of my code and use webpack as a bundler, ideally, I would want to use only the `vue-loader`.

Answer (score -1):

- you can't use import {} from ... without babel
- it's really hard to use babel without webpack
- you can't use vue-loader without webpack (read docs https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/)
- you can't use a vue component inside angularjs except by importing vue, which would make the page load too long

Comment: So according to your answer, there is no way to migrate from angular to vue.

Comment: you can but you need to remove angular in favor of vue at least in the new page